# Tracking one or more arbitrary, previously unknown objects with opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, object, tracking

as my question mentioned, does anyone know a way to track arbitrary, previously unknown objects
from a video feed with opencv-python?
Lets say we have a table and there are different objects on it. Suppose the objects begin to 
move as if by magic. Is there a possibility to keep track of each object?
I read something about Background Subtraction that highlights objects in the foreground. 
And I read something about Optical Flow that gives information about which pixels have
changed compared to the previous frame. 
I am a beginner in image processing and I am looking for a way to put it all together
and track arbitrary, previously unknown objects. 
I don't want to use a neural network in advance to find and classify the objects. I want
to track the objects as soon as they begin to move. One can assume that the camera is in a fixed position
with a fixed perspective onto the table. Is there a way to track an object
that has just begun to move? All I want to do is drawing a rectangle around the object and keep track of
it.
I don't want to do a classification of objects. I am not interested in the type of object, I am only
interested in the movement of the object.
Can someone give me an impulse?
Code examples would be very welcome.

Comment: Yes. Yes, but it won't be easy with [optical flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow). Yes, using [Phase Correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation). Unfortunately, I cannot help much more than this. Even though I would like to.

Comment: @ThePineapple Thank you for your reply. I will check this out and will let you know if I got it to work. If someone else has more ideas I would appreciate any help.